# Show only column value; not column name in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm trying to modify a script written in php, js with Yii. I simply need the value that I'm outputting to show up as a number without the column header. In this case, the number would be 20.

I'm using formulas.php to get the value that I need:

```
public function getMarkup()
{
    $mid=$this->getMerchantID();
    $DbExt=new DbExt;
    $stmt="SELECT markup FROM
        {{merchant}}
        WHERE
        merchant_id='$mid'
        LIMIT 0,1
    ";
    if ( $res=$DbExt->rst($stmt)){
        return $res[0];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then I'm calling the value on another page as:

```
<?php
    $anArray2=Yii::app()->functions->getMarkup();
    echo json_encode($anArray2);
?>
```

This returns:

```
{"markup":"20"}
```

I tried changing it to:

```
<?php
    echo Yii::app()->functions->getMarkup();
?>
```

And that returns:

```
Array
```

I'm trying to get it to return with just 20 (the value of the column) without the column header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
  echo Yii::app()->functions->getMarkup()["markup"];
?>
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: That is what I tried (listed above in my original post). That returns: Array. There may be something I can change on the functions.php (first code example), but I am still learning how to work with Yii. I just want it to output the number of the column value only.

Comment: Your, sir, are a rockstar! Thank you very, very much. I will accept the answer when it allows me to. Thanks again!